# Почему не работает FormData.append()?

Tags: javascript

```
var data = new FormData();
$.each( files, function( key, value ){
    data.append( key, value );
});
```

`files` - это массив с файлами, он точно не пустой, но в `data` ничего не добавляется.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

А как вы определили что туда ничего не добавляется?
Для проверки стоит использовать метод `getAll`.
Попробуйте этот пример:

```js
$('.files').change(function(ev) {
var item = $(this);
  
  var data = new FormData();
  
  $.each(ev.currentTarget.files, function (key, value) {
    data.append('files', value);
  });
  
  console.log(data.getAll('files'));
});
```

```html
<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"   integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<input name="file" class="files" type="file" multiple>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/05qj4tgL/